# Would title tags that are only slightly different still be considered duplicate titles?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content, title

I know that it's bad to use duplicate content, including duplicate titles. Does duplicate titles mean that they are 100% the same though?  Would there be enough distinction to not be considered duplicate by having small differences in their titles, like a unique number?

For example, assume that following are five different page titles.

- Square Root, Cube Root, Factors, Prime Check of 23
- Square Root, Cube Root, Factors, Prime Check of 24
- Square Root, Cube Root, Factors, Prime Check of 25
- Square Root, Cube Root, Factors, Prime Check of 26
- Square Root, Cube Root, Factors, Prime Check of 27

Would the above page titles be considered duplicate titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common for database driven sites to use templated pages with titles that differ only by a word or phrase plugged into a single location.   Having page titles that are very similar to others except for one word is not generally problematic.

Google treats numbers as unique elements of page titles.   You only have to do a Google search for things like:

- is 27 prime
- 27 factorization
- 27 cube root

You will see that Google does indeed take into account the "27" and most of the returned sites use "27" prominently in the title.  Some of the sites appear to be like yours and have pages for many different numbers.

You need to be very careful of violating [Google's webmaster guideline against automatically generated content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306).    Make sure your pages are different enough from each other in general that Google doesn't view them as low quality generated content.    There are a potentially infinite number of pages that you could create for all the numbers.   You obviously don't want to make infinite pages available to Googlebot.   You probably want to limit it to 100, as that will handle the majority of the numbers people would actually search for.  It would be ideal to have something written by an actual human about each and every number.

Since the number is the unique and important part of the title, I'd recommend putting it somewhere closer to the beginning.   I'd use something like:

> The Number 27: Square Root, Cube Root, Factors, Prime Check - My Brand

Answer (score 0):

With a quick look, the pages seem duplicate. It was kind of vague really of what content you are trying to make here. Are you planning of using a static page on each of the number or the pages here will be dynamic? I got an impression that the body/context of the page would have similar format with the title and that the content will be the same except for the values.